# How do I find the size of a directory on a Unix-like command-line?

Tags: command-line, unix

I know this is a very basic question, but I searched the web and did not find a simple answer.  I'm sure it's some kind of two or three letter command, right?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`du -s directory`, as in "disk usage, sum"

Use `du -sk` to show the size in kilobytes (default is to show number of 512-byte blocks), or `du -sh` for a more human-friendly output. For more options, type [`man du`](http://manpages.info/freebsd/du.1.html).

Comment: Actually I wanted 'du -s -b' so the size is in bytes.  I don't know why the default is kilobytes without a 'kb' but it wasn't a convincing answer!  ;D

Comment: You can use `-h` flag for 'human readable', this makes automatic conversion in KB, MB, ect.

Comment: @Martin this is my favorite flag as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as `-s`, but replace `0` with `1` and you can get just the content in the folder:

```
du -h -d 0 /path/to/file
```

If you want the whole volume, you should use df instead of du (path is optional):

```
df -H /
```

Off-topic: One (very) spooky thing: I happend to be just a street away from Arne Stenström.

/Robert